# Change specific value in PHP variable

Tags: php

I have a variable `$var` and it contain comma separated value.

```
$var = 'the_ring,hangover,wonder_woman';
```

I want to make it like below.

```
$var = 'The Ring,Hangover,Wonder Woman';
```

I tried `$parts = explode(',', $var);` also I tried **strpos()** and  **stripos()** but not able to figure it out.

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a string rather than an array?

Comment: data is coming from database actually.

Comment: why is the 2nd `$var` in Camel Case?

Comment: @Fred-ii- These are movie titles, which would be Camel Case :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- do i need to implode the array data. So, i can get the single variable.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine meaning that you want to assign a (different) variable to each value from the array?

Comment: no basically all value in a single variable like it was in $var earlier.

Comment: Hi Calculating Machine. As per a number of my edits to your questions, we try not to force home-made tags into questions here. We prefer [titles in natural English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256806/472495), and if you have a "tag" to put in, add it to the readable flow, or put it in the tag section. Would you be able to do that for your future questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$var = 'the_ring,hangover,wonder_woman';

$list = explode(',', $var);

$list = array_map( function($name){
    return ucwords(str_replace('_',' ', $name));
}, $list);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => The Ring
    [1] => Hangover
    [2] => Wonder Woman
)
```

Imploding:

```
$imploded = implode(',', $list);
```

Returns:

```
'The Ring,Hangover,Wonder Woman'
```

Comment: i need to implode the array then because they need data in single variable.

Comment: Man,  Why do you have to write too many lines of code to achieve something,  which can be done with few lines of code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to do your replace and uppercase:

```
$var = 'the_ring,hangover,wonder_woman';

$parts = explode(',', $var);

array_walk($parts, function(&$item){
    $item = str_replace('_', ' ', $item);
    $item = ucwords($item);
});

$var = implode(',', $parts);
```

Comment: This only makes the first word upper case - FYI

Answer (score 1):

Using str_replace() function [click here to](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp) explain

like this code

```
$str= 'the_ring,hangover,wonder_woman';

echo str_replace("_"," ","$str");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you replace `_` with **white spaces** using `str_replace()` function

```
$var = 'the_ring,hangover,wonder_woman';
echo str_replace("_"," ",$var);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = 'the_ring,hangover,wonder_woman';
$var1 = explode(',' $var);

foreach ($var1 as $key => $value) {
   $var1[$key]=str_replace("_"," ",$value);
   $var1[$key]=ucwords($var1[$key]);
}
```

`$var = implode(',', $var1);`

Answer (score -1):

1.use str_replace to replace something in the string. In your case _ is replaced with space
2.use ucFirst method to capitalize every first character in the strings

```
$replaced = str_replace('_', ' ', $var);
$changed = ucfirst($replaced);
```